# update a group by with a double left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a specific select that already shows me the data I would need to know.
It contains a group by and 2 cross joins. Table "Projekt" is the table with all the projects, table "Bestellung" can contain several orders for that project, table "Lieferung" can contain several deliveries for one order. I need to get the last date in the table "Lieferung and put it into a field in the table "Projekt". Here's the select that shows the maxdate of the last delivery for a project.

```
SELECT  Projekt.ProjNr, MAX(Lieferung.LSDatum) AS Expr1
FROM    Lieferung RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     Bestellung ON Lieferung.BestellNr = Bestellung.BestellNr RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     Projekt ON Bestellung.VorgangsNr = Projekt.ProjNr
GROUP BY Projekt.ProjNr
```

I now need to update the project table with the maxdate, I have read that you cannot use group by in an update query, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can however join your target update table with a subquery:

```
UPDATE P
SET
 <updateField> = Expr1
FROM Projekt P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  Projekt.ProjNr, MAX(Lieferung.LSDatum) AS Expr1
    FROM    Lieferung RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         Bestellung ON Lieferung.BestellNr = Bestellung.BestellNr RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         Projekt ON Bestellung.VorgangsNr = Projekt.ProjNr
    GROUP BY Projekt.ProjNr
) P1 ON
    P.ProjNr = P1.ProjNr
```